# how can i protect the data beacon/ble sent?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

So basically what i want to do is, let my app keep sending package/ receiving package so I know which people i met before. the sending data is easy: i just need a uuid to identify that this is my app, and a number or string to represent which user it represents. Now the question is, how can I make it secure? Let's say if anyone who can detect it, then he can mock a exactly same package and send out, then if he stand next to me, my app will believe that he is the user even he is not(he mocked).

iBeacon is absolutely not fit this requirement because its uuid/major/minor can be easily detected. One way i can think of is using BLE instead of iBeacon to writing the encrypting data in a service, then the question is can anyone else easily mock a service with the data he detect?

Comment: This is more of an encryption question than a beacon question.  You would need to encrypt the real identifier combined with a timestamp using a secret key shared

Answer (score 0):

The typical solution is to combine the real identifier with a timestamp and encrypt the pair using a secret key.  This produces an encrypted identifier that constantly changes and is worthless unless you can decode it.  Once decoded, the timestamp protects against replay attacks -- it must be within a small interval from the current time for the decrypted identifier to be considered valid.

Obviously, this solution requires synchronized clocks on the transmitter and receiver.

The details of the implementation are more of an encryption question than a beacon question.  And the devil is in the details.

Comment: Yes you are right. And looks like the exchanging data requires your device to connect with the app u got the signal, and it can only been connected as most as 7. And, I just saw someone posted an answer that your app should not be connect with other device if you want your app to be both peripherals and central at same time?  My case is, I need to keep sending and getting the data when I go to the street and keep meet people over and over, which is impossible to connect to each device right?(let's suppose they all have this app installed).

Comment: Does there has a solution that I can let this app sending/receiving package at same time, while not requires connect when I detect them?  All I want is like a filter, keep filter the data and save the user id, while keep the identifier/user_id secure. Thanks David!

Comment: You don't need to establish a connection to do this.  The encrypted identifier may be sent by the beacon device in transmit only mode.  You may also send the timestamp in clear text (in addition to being used to create the encrypted identifier) so the beacon does not need to have a real time clock.  This way the receiving devices (e.g. the phones) simply decrypt the encrypted identifier, and verify the timestamp inside that encrypted payload is within an appropriate period of the timestamp sent in clear text.  If so, you can trust the actual identifier inside the encrypted payload.

Comment: What do u mean by clean text? shouldn't  I just send an encrypted  identifier(identifier+time stamp and then encrypt it)? In my case there is no other beacons, all the device which send receive is the app itself. I think what you are saying is, only use transmit mode to send and receive without connecting with the payload right David ?

Comment: Yes, only use transmit mode without a connection.  Since you are sending from one phone to another, you can be confident the clocks are in sync, so  you can just send the encrypted identifier as you say.

Comment: Hi David where can i put my customized data?  I found only CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey is the potential place but when i construct a value as type [CBUUID: NSData] it complained.                                             let ad = [CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey: "test",
                      CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey: [serviceUUID],
                      CBAdvertisementDataIsConnectable: false,
                      CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey: []]

Comment: Since I don't connect, looks like advertisementData is the only place to insert my customized data (identifier + timestamp + userId then encrypting), which key can i use? I tried CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey and i customized key and it didn't work :(

Comment: Sorry, iOS actually will not let you do send a custom BLE advertisement  transmission with arbitrary data.  It lets you decode service data, but you cannot transmit it.  This means your iOS devices cannot be transmitters using a system like this.

Comment: then how can i do this you mentioned above?  "You don't need to establish a connection to do this. The encrypted identifier may be sent by the beacon device in transmit only mode. You may also send the timestamp in clear text (in addition to being used to create the encrypted identifier) so the beacon does not need to have a real time clock"   where should i put the text into if i don't need to connect?

Comment: When I described the solution, I did not realize you intended to use an iOS device as the transmitter.  That is the part that is not possible.  You can use an Android device as a transmitter or a dedicated BLE hardware device.  But iOS simply won't let you transmit arbitrary advertisement data bytes.  Again, Android and dedicated BLE hardware chips do allow this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply David. Yes my intention is to write an iOS app that can detect and gather who I met at a certain time range. That's to say, this app need to be able to both transmit its signal and receive signal from other my apps. So first, it need to be both a central and peripheral. Second, it needs to send out some small data such as user_id. Third it can do this in background mode.  Basically like a iOS app called "wantsme”

Comment: Any suggestions that I can make the device both central and peripheral and make connections as well?